# Overriding default_scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, default-scope

In my Post.rb model, I have `default_scope :conditions => {:deleted => 'false'}`

But if I try to run `Post.find(:all, :conditions => "deleted='false'")`, it won't return anything.  It's as if the default_scope takes precedence over everything.

I want it so that when I do `Post.find()` it doesn't return deleted posts, but I'd also like to be able to access them if I need to.  What needs to be changed in either my query or my Rails model?

Thanks.

Comment: `default_scope` *does* take precedence over everything. I wrote an answer using `named_scope` to your previous question that I think would be applicable here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073197/how-to-get-a-model-to-specify-a-pre-requisite-condition/2073858#2073858

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`with_exclusive_scope` is `protected`, so you have to create a class method:

```
def self.include_deleted_in
  Event.with_exclusive_scope { yield }
end
```

then in your controller call

```
Post.include_deleted_in { Post.find(:all) }
```

Comment: Event.with_exclusive_scope { yield } doesn't worked for me, i had to put Post.with_exclusive_scope { yield }. Anyway great answer. Save my life today.

Answer (score 60):

This one was somehow left hidden :)

Just use `Post.unscoped.where(:deleted => true)`, if you're using Rails 3

Credit goes to [José Valim](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/07/new-active-record-scoping-syntax/) for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when the default_scope has an :order clause and you want to override that.

Comment: Zabba, that was exactly my case and this worked flawlessly for me. thanks edgerunner.

Comment: @Zabba, use `reorder` for that

Comment: Be careful with this one.  If you're working with an association `unscoped` will blow that away too.

Answer (score 1):

use [with_exclusive_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/with_exclusive_scope/class)

```
 Post.with_exclusive_scope { Post.find(:all) }
```

Comment: Using this (outside Post model) results in:

protected method `with_exclusive_scope' called for #<Class:0x10faf5c70>

Comment: You can use `Post.send(:with_exclusive_scope) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are meant to be composable, meaning you can combine a bunch of them and it effectively applies all the conditions.  In this case ActiveRecord is just too naive to determine that the explicit condition should negate the first one.  It just builds the query joining all the clauses with ANDs.  For this reason default_scope has the most utility with the :order clauses which is not composable (in ActiveRecord 2.3's implementation anyway).  There is more discussion [here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping).

Also note that in Rails 3 ActiveRecord is using [Arel](http://github.com/nkallen/arel) for a lot of query construction which will greatly increase the power of ActiveRecord query generation while simplifying a lot of the internals.  It's likely that with Arel will improve your situation.  In the meantime I recommend not putting conditions in a default_scope unless there are rows that you really want to be invisible to your Rails app.