# Rails 3.1.3 unscoped scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, default-scope

I've seen a lot of posts regarding this, but none seem to solve my problem. I have a `default_scope` on a model like so:

```
default_scope where(:is_active => true).order('LOWER(table.name)');
```

I have other (normal) scopes, and I want to create an `inactive` scope using `unscoped`. I would like to define it as a scope, but it only works when defined as a class method:

```
# works
def self.inactive
  unscoped { where(:is_active => false) }
end

# none of these work
scope :inactive, unscoped { where(:is_active => false) }
scope :inactive, with_exclusive_scope { where(:is_active => true) }
scope :inactive, unscoped.where(:is_active => false)
scope :inactive, lambda { unscoped { where(:is_active => false) } }
scope :inactive, unscoped { lambda { where(:is_active => false) } }
unscoped do
  scope :inactive, where(:is_active => false)
end
```

Is there a way that I missed, or do I have to use a class method to define this scope?

Comment: Kind of similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919307/rails-3-default-scope-scope-with-overrride

Comment: (if you read the comments there, there's not really a solution)

Comment: I would say also look into `except` and `only` but they don't seem to negate the `default_scope` from within another scope, similar to the problem with `unscoped` and `with_exclusive_scope`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `scope :inactive, unscoped.where(:is_active => false)` works perfectly fine for me on a Rails 3.1.3 app. I tried it on a `User` class and calling `User.inactive` gives me only those records where `is_active` is `false`.

Comment: @DylanMarkow - did you have the `default_scope` set to `where(:is_active => true)`?

Comment: it's not working for me... what version of ruby?

Comment: @DylanMarkow are you defining your `scope` before or after `default_scope`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this. I opened an issue on the rails repo on github...

Comment: As a work around, you can create a class method that uses unscoped and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scope :inactive, lambda { unscoped.where(:is_active => false) }
```

Comment: ftr, neither doesn unscoped { lambda {...} }