# Model to implement users (Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, model

I am implementing a User that is not actually deleted from the system with destroy but only marked with `:active = false`.

The problem here is that such an inactivate user will show up in all `User.find`, `User.all`, ... calls. I don't want to pollute the code with all kinds of 'if-else's or overwriting the behavior of `.find`, `.all` etc.

I just want to know whether I can nicely define it within the User's model so that inactive users will virtually disappear unless I explicitly want to extract such a user.

If there is no way to do it in the model then what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to check `acts_as_paranoid` Here is a link for one of the implementations: https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid

From the wiki:

> Now whenever destroy is called on that model, it is just removed from view and the deleted_at column set to the current date time. All the finder methods ignore “deleted” records.

Comment: That *is* a simple mechanism to implement the filtering you want, as is a default scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [scope](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html), or a [class method with a `where` clause](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/).

Comment: Scopes are fine; the issue in the post was fixed. `acts_as_paranoid` is a pre-built solution if you don't already have everything set up as @socjopata said.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not exactly what I wanted. As far as I read through the material 'scope' is just some kind of class function, and I will still have to type 'User.activated.find(...)'. I wanted an initial filtering of such records from the class unless I specify that I want to see them.

Comment: Set a default scope, and override when necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073419/overriding-default-scope-in-rails

Comment: Thanks again! Yep, it looks nice. Anyway, i have added a class method for active users.